# How to treat complex values when writing a numpy ufunc?

Tags: c, numpy, complex-numbers, numpy-ufunc

Basically I have a numpy ufunc that operates on `npy_cdouble` and `npy_cfloat` arrays. For instance:

```
static void
ufunc_H( char ** args
       , npy_intp * dimensions
       , npy_intp * steps
       , void * data)
{

    npy_cdouble * qm_in = (npy_cdouble *) (args[0]);
    npy_cdouble * qm_out = (npy_cdouble *) (args[1]);
    npy_intp i;

    for(i = 0; i < ndim; i++)
    {
        qm_out[i] = (qm_in[i] - qm_in[i ^ ipow(2, argument.act)]) * M_SQRT1_2;
    }


}
```

This however does not work and the compiler says that `qm_in` has the type `‘npy_cdouble’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’}`. How do I treat `npy_cdouble` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The structures `npy_cdouble` and `npy_cfloat` have the members `.real` and `.imag`. Those can be used to do operations:

```
static void
ufunc_H( char ** args
       , npy_intp * dimensions
       , npy_intp * steps
       , void * data)
{

    npy_cdouble * qm_in = (npy_cdouble *) (args[0]);
    npy_cdouble * qm_out = (npy_cdouble *) (args[1]);
    npy_intp i;

    for(i = 0; i < ndim; i++)
    {
        qm_out[i].real = (qm_in[i].real - qm_in[i ^ ipow(2, argument.act)].real) * M_SQRT1_2;
        qm_out[i].imag = (qm_in[i].imag - qm_in[i ^ ipow(2, argument.act)].imag) * M_SQRT1_2;
    }


}
```